# Information about android:foregroundInsidePadding

Tags: android, xml, layout

In framelayout, I want use the android:foregroundInsidePadding attribute but there is no documentation about this attribute (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

When i write android:foregroundInsidePadding="true", i have an error 
"error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'foregroundInsidePadding' in package 'android'"

Anyone have info on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foregroundInsidePadding` defines whether the foreground drawable should be drawn inside the padding. This property is false by default except if your background is a NinePatch Drawable.
Just add:

```
custom:foregroundInsidePadding="true"
```

Refer [this](https://github.com/cesards/ForegroundViews/blob/master/README.md).